# android studio error: The surrounding layout did not include this layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I have two questions:

1)
I tried to add a button on the `activity_main.xml`, It shows. Then I think the button is better to be placed in the `content_main.xml`. This time the button doesn't show in the content_main.xml. I made the button visibility property to visible and the content_main visibility property to visible as well. But the button still did not show.

There was a warning: The surrounding `layout (@layout/activity_main)` did not actually include this layout. Remove `tools:showIn=...` from the root tag.

I guess the reason the button does not show up is that the `activity_main.xml` doesn't include the `content_main.xml`. If it is the cause, how to solve the problem?

2)
The options menu (for settings) displays on the centre of the toolbar, not right end. How to fix it?

Comment: where is the code and errorlog??

Comment: past your xml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>
```

write these line in activity_main to include content_main layout in activity_main

Answer (score 0):

You can use-:

```
<include layout="YourLayout.xml"/>
```

you can make this xml and use it anywhere you want.